# Adding value of a vector to another using Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a vector of values I need to add to a second vector at indices specified by another vector. How do I accomplish this using Octave/Matlab?

EDIT: 
v1 = [1 2 3 4]

v2 = [0 0]

indices = [1 2 1 2]

output = [4 6]

The first and third elements of v1 are added to index 1 of v2, and second and fourth element of v1 are added to second element of v2.

Comment: Could you please give a small reproducible example of all your vectors (& desired output)? It would make it easier for us to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you mean (if you provide a small example in your question it's easier to understand).

You have a vector of values

```
toAdd = 1:5;
```

You have a second, bigger vector:

```
bigVector = 1:10;
```

You want to do `bigVector + toAdd`, where you add the elements of `toAdd` at *specific* indices into `bigVector`, specified by:

```
indices = [1 3 5 7 9];
```

That is, you want the output vector:

```
[ bigVector(1)+toAdd(1);
  bigVector(2);
  bigVector(3)+toAdd(2);
  bigVector(4);
  bigVector(5)+toAdd(3);
  ....
 ]
```

In that case, you can do the following:

```
outputVector = bigVector;
outputVector(indices) = bigVector(indices) + toAdd;
```

In particular, notice the `outputVector(indices)` and `bigVector(indices)`, which selects the elements of `outputVector` and `bigVector` specified by the vector `indices`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
for k=unique(indices),
    v2(k) = v2(k) + sum(v1(indices==k));
end
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but it looks like you won't need to add the sum to v2(k) so just:
for k=unique(indices),
    v2(k) = sum(v1(indices==k));
end

Comment: In the question it says "The first and third elements of v1 **are added** to index 1 of v2". So v2 might have different initial values even though it is zero in this case.

Comment: I agree - but It could mean that they are added to each other and then placed in index 1 etc... Either way I agree with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's......

```
v2 = accumarray(indices, v1)
```